# Which Python files should be added to a Git repository?

Tags: python, git, gitignore

I'm new to Python and recently wrote a script. Now, I have to push this script to gitlab, but I don't quite understand which files should be committed and pushed.

After initializing a .git file in my project folder, `git status` gives the following:

```
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .idea/
        desktop.ini
        venv/
```

Since all of my files are untracked, `git add .` does not work, and I am hesitant to add them by force, so to speak.

As far as I understand, virtualenvs should not be added to Git, so that leaves me with only .idea and desktop.ini. Should I add both, and is there some sort of general rule to go by when committing and pushing files?

Comment: .idea and desktop.ini do not belong to your Python project and should not be added to the Git repository. You should only add the Python file that you wrote somewhere (we can't see it here).

Comment: @mkrieger1 Not all `.idea` files should be ignored, project structure files like `modules.xml` can and should be committed to git.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gitignore+python , https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/api/python

Comment: @mkrieger1 The script is in venv\main.py

Comment: @Guy this is only true if everyone dealing with the project uses PyCharm. My `.idea/whatever` is useless for teammate that uses Visual Studio Code. So in general, most `.gitignore` templates ignores whole `.idea/`

Comment: @lokindo venv should only contain the virtual environment (and be not committed). Your project files should be outside the venv folder. The usual location is: `projectdir/venv` for venv only, project files themselves directly in `projectdir/` or in `projectdir/src`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking back at this, the problem was that I somehow managed to place the code files inside of the venv, so all I needed was to structure my project files correctly, and everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can add Github's Python [.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Python.gitignore) to ignore non-project/personal config files.

All should not be pushed, `.idea` contains personal PyCharm config, venv is your Python [Virtual ENVironment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html). `desktop.ini` appears to be a file for Windows which should also not be on git.

Comment: I understand, thank you! But if i ignore these files, I won't have any left to commit/push

Comment: @lokindo that means you have not written any code? You would ideally want to push code to Github (eg: `.py` and `.ipynb` files). If you still want to make a commit, you can add a `README.md`

Answer (score 1):

none of them should be pushed. I think you have not commit you script yet.

Comment: why not type in your file name
git add <yourfilenamehere>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).